# Convert embedded .swf to HTML5

Tags: html, flash

I'd like to convert a `.swf` file (containing embedded `.swf` files) into HTML5. I've tried Google's Swiffy converter, producing a nearly complete HTML5 version of the Flash widget.

However, Swiffy seems to have issues with the embedded files. I converted the embedded `.swf` files to HTML5 and attempted to edit the generated JS from Swiffy to use the converted embedded files but no luck.

Is there a way to convert `.swf` files with embedded `.swf` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue of embedded `.swf` using this process:

1. Convert the master `.swf` file to a `.html` file using [Swiffy](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en).
2. Using Dev Tools I was able to see the converted `.swf` master file was looking for the embedded `.swf` files as `.swf.json` files.
3. I ran the embedded `.swf` files through [Swiffy](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en) to turn them into `.html` files.
4. Open the `.html` files you'll see a `swiffyobject` in the JS code in the header. The `swiffyobject` is a JSON-formatted object. Copy the object - everything in the `{}`, including the brackets.
5. Paste the object into a new file, save the file and append `.json` to the filename. For example, if your original embedded file was `child.swf`, the new filename would be `child.swf.json`. Save it in the place the master `.swf` was expecting it. This might be a subdirectory.
6. When you open the master `.swf` file (converted to a `.html` file it should now be able to load the embedded `.swf.json` files.